# Design pattern to return an internal table of various types

Tags: generics, inheritance, design-patterns, abap, abstraction

[The documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapmethods_functional.htm) states: return parameters of functional methods have to be fully typed.

I'm trying to dance around that prerequisite in the following case:

I have a program where the user picks an object on screen 1000 and can make various changes to it on screen 2000. The objects that the user can pick are of varied types. The object is presented on screen 2000 in an ALV, where the columns depend on the object's type. The program handles the user actions in mostly the same way no matter the object type.

The way the program is laid out is: an abstract class defines the default behaviour for all object types, then a child-class for each object type redefines methods where needed.

The class handling the object's data has the method `get_data_ref()`. This method returns a reference to a private internal table from the subclass, that contains an object's data. This internal table is declared in each subclass with a different row type.

An abstract method `get_fieldcatalog()` returns the fieldcatalog for the given object type. This method is redefined in each of the subclasses.

To display the ALV, I get the table reference from `get_data_ref()`, assign a field symbol to it and pass the field symbol to the ALV using method `SET_TABLE_FOR_FIRST_DISPLAY()` along with the fieldcatalog.

It works. But it is wrong.

- It gives direct access to a private attribute of my class by
  referencing it. The private internal table can be altered from
  outside of the class, which is against the abstraction principle.
- Is it safe ? Could the internal table be freed from memory while a pointer to it still existed ?

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: take a look at the [proxy pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern) and its [implementation in ABAP](http://zevolving.com/2012/01/abap-objects-design-patterns-proxy/), but your overall design looks wrong and overcomplicated

Comment: @Suncatcher: could you elaborate on the proxy pattern please ? I do not see how I could use it in my case. Also why is my design overcomplicated ?

Comment: I'd say it's against the SOLID Open-Closed Principle, not abstraction. I agree that it's not safe. You can use a parameter of category `EXPORTING` and type `ANY`, instead of `RETURNING` which needs to be fully typed as you said. Note that there is a Table Sharing when you only copy an internal table without changing it. You could also make your classes be responsible of managing the grid view instead of being only used for storing data, you might use inheritance to avoid repeating code.

Comment: @SandraRossi with `EXPORTING`, the problem is that the internal table has to be declared (and fully typed) in the calling class, where the type of the table isn't supposed to be known (hence generics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a generic `EXPORTING` parameter instead of a `RETURNING` one in the `get_data()` method (as suggested by **Sandra Rossi**) and returning a RTTS object through a separate `GET_TABLEDESCR( )` method. In the calling class the internal table is typed at runtime using the descriptor object.

In the calling class:

```
DATA(lo_tabledescr) = go_data->GET_TABLEDESCR( ).
CREATE DATA lr_dref TYPE HANDLE lo_tabledescr.

ASSIGN lr_dref->* TO <lt_table>.
CHECK <lt_table> IS ASSIGNED.
go_data->GET_DATA( changing ct_data = <lt_table> ).
```

In the class of `go_data`:

```
METHOD GET_TABLEDESCR. " This method returns ro_descr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr
  DATA lo_structdescr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr.
  lo_structdescr ?= CL_ABAP_STRUCTDESCR=>DESCRIBE_BY_NAME( P_NAME = 'your_linetype_name' ).

  ro_descr = cl_abap_tabledescr=>GET(
    exporting
      P_LINE_TYPE  = lo_structdescr      " Row Type
  ).
ENDMETHOD.
```